# I used cylinder projection on this cylinder, but now there is a noticeable seam when i apply any texture, How can I make it seamless?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

-Cylinder Projection used for Unwrapping-

[image]

Comment: You need a texture that is seamless.

Comment: Oh so its the texture thats causing it i c

Comment: If the texture is not a seamless one you will see the edge.

Comment: I guess it's worth mentioning that @brockmann's answer works because the  Voronoi from the Blender node is 3D, The rendered surfaces are slices through mathematically calculated Voronoi 'chunks'.

Comment: Feel free to edit my post @RobinBetts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You actually don't need any UVs nor a seamless texture in this case.**

The given texture is just a [voronoi pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram), which can be generated on the fly in shader using the *Voronoi Texture* node. If you want a bump map: create a second voronoi node, set it's feature output to 'Distance to Edge' and keep 'Scale' and 'Randomness' parameters in sync by using a *Value* node:

[image]

Recommend have a look into the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/voronoi.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip man, For now i used a seamless texture but would definitely keep this in mind next time i do voronoi textures.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a non-seamless texture seamless, but you can find workarounds by using photoshop, or another program to make the texture seamless. I would either find a new texture, or use another program to make it seamless. There aren't too many other options, but finding a truly seamless texture should be pretty easy.

Comment: Yeah i found a seamless texture and now its all good.